# Finding the shortest path through a maze

Tags: graph, traversal

Just a quicky.  Will a Breadth First Search always find you the shortest path through a maze ? (As opposed to a Depth First Search)

Comment: I think both algorithms can find the shortest path eventually.  Can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: I am generally looking at the concept of Graph Traversals...at beginner level. Based on your feedback, I can therefore deduce that DFS or BFS can both be an ideal solution, depending on the properties of the graph. ?

Comment: I agree with what you said.

Comment: Both searches will eventually produce the shortest path. However, a DFS may be grossly inefficient in doing so without enhancements. Consider a 10x10 grid to cross from bottom left to top right. With BFS there will be 2 * 10 * 11 edge visits, naive DFS may end up with more than 2^10 visits ( depending on the order of visitation, path portions will be  traversed multiple times ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Both algorithms eventually check all possible routes, so they will find the shortest path.

The real question here is efficiency...